Can I specify certain windows to remain open (not minimized) when using Stage Manager?
I recently enabled Stage ManagerIt does help a lot for organizing the desktop.
Subsequently I was in a Zoom meeting and wanted to share my IDE contents . Due to this setting being active it was not possible to do so: I either get Zoom or the IDE: the other gets minimized.
Is there a way to say "yea I like this feature, but I do need to keep Zoom and Pycharm [but only those] fully open / non-minimized"?  If not then how do other folks organize their desktop along those lines [of not keeping everything open/non-minimized all the  time] ?
Update I am looking at the Stage Manager Docs and there appears to possible to drag a thumbnail into the current screen to group them. Let's see if that goes where I need.

The Stage Manager does allow grouping of applications. You drag the app's thumbnail from the left side into the main Desktop area when you have the Group you want it to be added to open. Initially the "Group" is just one application: but then you can sequentially add apps to that "group". Now those apps can be accessed without causing the other ones in the same group to be minimized.  To remove an app from that group you drag it all the way to the left of the screen and then it gets minimized to the Dock.  Really nifty!

